# WT901BLE not showing/advertising service UUID to the ESP32

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, esp32, arduino-esp32, pairing

We are pairing WT901BLE device with the ESP32.When WT901BLE is paired with smart phone application NRFConnect then service UUID is shown. I have read on some forums that some devices don't advertise service UUID and ESP32 only analyzes advertised data so that's why ESP32 can't see the service UUID of WT901BLE.Someone proposed on git to a similar issue that library code need to be updated for ESP32 to read scan response for data other than advertised data also then it will work. Can someone tell whether this is the only solution or there is some better way to do it. Secondly, which library need to be updated to get the desired result?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask where you saw the suggestion about updating the library.

Comment: I have asked there:
https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/612
 I have a deadline of the project tomorrow and need urgent response